# prepared statement invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Okay so I've been starting at this for an hour now, it says "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in..." Iv'e counted them out and they are right. Any ideas?

```
 $sql="insert into myTable (TicketID ,Priority, Status, Summary, Description, Category, Customer,
                AssignedGroup, AssignedTo, OpenedDate, ResolvedDate, ClosedDate, FinalDescription, RootCause, ResolutionCode)
               values(:tid,:pri,:stat,:summ,:descr,:cat,:cus,:assG,:assT,:opnDate,:resDate,:cloDate:,finDesc,:root,:resCode)";
        $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':tid', $data[0]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pri', $data[1]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':stat', $data[2]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':summ', $data[3]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':descr', $data[4]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cat', $data[5]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cus', $data[6]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':assG', $data[7]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':assT', $data[8]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':opnDate', $Odate);
        $stmt->bindParam(':resDate', $RDate);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cloDate', $CDate);
        $stmt->bindParam(':finDesc', $data[12]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':root', $data[13]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':resCode', $data[14]);

        try{
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `:` here in query

```
cloDate,:finDesc,
        ^ // here
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this part:-

```
:cloDate:,finDesc
```

to

```
:cloDate,:finDesc
```